# Editing sudoers file on two Macbooks yields different result

Tags: osx, sudo

I just wanted to execute the command *ntpdate* without typing in a password so I edited the sudoers file via Emacs editor. I simply added one line of code at the end of the file

```
Boris Boris-MacBook-Air.local = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ntpdate
```

I have two Macbooks. One is of 2011 model with EL Capitan OS and sudo version 1.7.10p9. The other is of 2017 model with High Sierra OS and sudo version 1.8.17p1. I did the same thing on both computers. It works on the 2011 Macbook but in case of the 2017 Macbook, after editing, when I call $sudo it prints out an error message.

> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 63
>
> sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 63
>
> sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
>
> sudo: unable to initiate policy plugin

This are lines 60-62

```
# Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```

I cannot make any sense out of this that why it does not work on the new laptop

Comment: What is on line 61,62, 63, and 64 of your sudoers file ? You may replace username with jdoe, jsmith, jane, bob etc if you want ;-)
`sed -n '61,64p' /etc/sudoers`

Comment: `sudo` has come different syntax depending on the version, even in Linux. Unfortunately my Mac is not at hand atm.  Please follow the @thecarpy recommendation of not obfuscating so much the real syntax you are using, so we can understand what is happening.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro is right, please provide the version of `sudo` for both systems. `sudo -V`
It is good practice on here to update your question with this information, so everybody can see it without going through all comments...

Comment: I edited the syntax to the real one I use, sorry about that. The 2011 MacBook has sudo version 1.7.10p9 and the 2017 MacBook has sudo version1.8.17p1.

Answer (score 2):

Following is the preamble of the `sudoers` file on my Mac. (I don't believe its wording has changed in the past fifteen years.)

> This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
>    Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
>    that prevent sudo from running.
>
> See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.

Here's a snippet from the `visudo man page`:

> After the edits are made, **visudo** parses the **sudoers** file. It will not save the changes if there is a syntax error.
>
> Upon finding an error, **visudo** will print a message stating the line number(s) where the error occurred and the user will receive a **"What now?"** prompt.  At this point, the user may enter **e** to re-edit the sudoers file, **x** to exit without saving the changes, or **Q** to quit and save changes.
>
> The **Q** option should be used with extreme care because if **visudo** believes there is a parse error, so will **sudo**, and ***no one*** will be able to sudo again until the error is fixed.  If **e** is typed to edit the **sudoers** file after a parse error has been detected, the cursor will be placed on the line where the error occurred.

. . . And that's the reason I actually *use* `visudo` instead of, say, `nano`. If there's a problem, `visudo` will warn me and direct me to it before I commit and lock not just myself, but *everybody* out of root access. (Like I did fifteen years ago, not that I'll admit it.) Anyway, since `$sudo` is complaining about a syntax error on a non-existent line number, I'd bet it's a stray EOF character or similar typocrud causing the problem.